# def firstDigit(n) (returning the first digit of the argument)?

Tags: python

I am not sure how to do these problems. Please help!

> Write the following functions and provide a program to test them.
>
> 1. `def firstDigit(n)` (returning the first digit of the argument)
> 2. `def lastDigit(n)` (returning the last digit of the argument)
> 3. `def digits(n)` (returning the number of digits in the argument)

Here's what I have so far:

```
def firstDigit(1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
    """Return the first digit of the argument."""

print(firstDigit[0])
```

Comment: I have a question. What is n? (Int, List). I have this question because you first define the function firstDigit(n) but then you call to the function as follows def firstDigit(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: Sorry that was my attempt at the code but it did not work.

Comment: Do not worry I understand. But then **n** is a number(Int)?

Comment: Yes, n is a number. Like this, "For example,  firstDigit(1729) is 1,  lastDigit(1729) is 9, and  digits(1729) is 4. Provide a program that tests your functions."

Comment: Ok. I just proposed a solution.

Comment: Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271299/how-can-i-get-the-first-two-digits-of-a-number) to get it done.

Comment: @MetaLNadia You could improve the description of your problem a bit so that more people can understand. Consider that you can place the code that you have implemented and where it is failing so that the community can help you.

Comment: @Gasanov Great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that n is a integer. I propose the following solution:

```
def firstDigit(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    return int(n_str[0])

def lastDigit(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    return int(n_str[-1])


def digits(n):
    n_str = str(n)
    return len(n_str)

#Some cases.
print(firstDigit(1729))
print(lastDigit(1729))
print(digits(1729))
```