# Take first digit from a integer - py

Tags: python

Is it possible, to the the first digit of a integer, for example: `num = 1010`
, so you take the 1 from the num variable out and put it into another integer?

for example:

```
num = 1010
num_2 = (first digit of num)

num_2 + 2 * 2
```

Comment: `int(str(n)[0])`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the first two digits of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271299/how-can-i-get-the-first-two-digits-of-a-number)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution that avoids `str` and recursion consider:

```
from math import log10

n = 1010
n // (10 ** int(log10(n)))
```

Comment: This is subject to errors from float precision. For example, it does not work for ``n = 999999999999999`` given 64bit ``float``s.

Comment: That's interesting and good to know.  This particular case seems to go away with replacing `log10(n)` with `log(n, 10)` but can be reproduced with even more 9's.  I don't know enough about the implementation of `log10` to understand further (just log2(n) / log2(10)?).  I can see that this approach generally will be sensitive to float error in calculating the number of base 10 digits of n.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can convert it to a string, take the first character of that string, then convert that to an int.

```
num = 1010
num_2 = int(str(num)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
num2 = int(re.sub(r'(.).*', '\\1', str(num)))
```

This removes all but the first digit of `num`. The `str` conversion is needed for `re.sub` to work (it requires a string), and the `int` conversion is needed for subsequent arithmetic operations to work.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do it the hard way, divide the number by 10 until the result is less than 10:

```
def first_digit(n):
    while n > 10:
        n //= 10
    return n
```